# How do I list all of the executables in a Linux (directory, + sub-dirs, $PATH)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

How can I list all executables (programs) and shell scripts in a directory, sub-directory and/or PATH?

I am not talking about software that was installed with apt-get or any package manager. Using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Adjacently related: [Unix & Linux: How to pipe the list of commands displayed by "tab complete"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23900/114401)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `ls`, for example:

```
ls *.bin *.py
```

Add any other extensions you wish to list on the command line.

A better way would be to use `find`, for example:

1. Do a recursive search from the current directory

   ```
   find . -type f -executable
   ```
2. Search the current directory

   ```
   find . -type f -executable -maxdepth 1
   ```

Note: The dot after `find` means search from the current directory. Change it as needed to search from other directories.

Comment: This did not work on a Mac, but @utobi's answer `find . -type f -perm -u+x` did.

Answer (score 2):

One way to search for all executables in the current directory and its subdirectories is:

```
find . -type f -perm -u+x -ls
```

Here `-type f` looks for regular files only, `-perm -u+x` looks for files with executable permission properly set and `-ls` lists the matched files.

Comment: You have partly answered the question in identifying executables within the current directory. The poster has explicitly also asked for executables under `$PATH`.

Comment: @fswings yes, you are right of course. But as stated in another answer, to search in other dirs the OP can just change the `.` to a suitable directory.

Answer (score 0):

If your'e the "creative" type, an `ls` command can show colorings for executable types as seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/color-meanings-in-terminal). May not be as useful as filtering, but hey, it looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly POSIX compliant but using some GNU stuff, this get's all executables in `$PATH` and recursively from current dir.

```sh
sed 'y/:\n/\x00\x00/' <<< "$PATH" |\
  xargs -0 -I% \
  find % -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable |\
  cat <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable)
# remove -maxdepth 1 to include sub-dirs
```

Not sure why one would want executables in sub-dirs but omit `-maxdepth 1` to include those.